# testing click behavior on React Router Links with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

While I'm ultimately trying to write an Enzyme test for  the flow in this react router example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
const MockComp = () => (
  <div className="protected">
    <nav>hi</nav>
    Protected
  </div>
);
const MockDenied = () => <div className="denied">Denied</div>;

test('Renders visited protected component if authorized', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
      <div>
        <Link to="/foo" />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/401" component={MockDenied} />
          <ProtectedRouteBasic
            path="/foo"
            auth={{ hasAuth: true }}
            component={MockComp}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  wrapper.find('a').simulate('click', { button: 0 });
  expect(wrapper.find('.protected').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(wrapper.find('.denied').length).toEqual(0);
});
```

I've found a number of issues and have tried to peel away the complexity and then slowly reintroduce the elements that I've removed.

So I've landed on this test as what I will need to get working to proceed:

```
test('Clicking link will render component associated with path', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/foo" />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/foo" component={MockComp} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  wrapper.find('a').simulate('click', { button: 0 });
  expect(wrapper.find('.protected')).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

However, this test isn't working as expected as I expect the test to pass in its current state.  I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651092/enzyme-integration-testing-testing-with-react-router-testing-components-update) to update my `simulate` call to include the `{button: 0}` as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531465/how-to-test-react-router-with-enzyme) about wrapping the entire router in a functional component, however, that option's not available to me as far as I know, since the [framework I'm working with](http://fusionjs.com) doesn't seem to allow for it.  Additionally, I believe that that piece is immaterial to the issue I'm having.  That said, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Switch docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch):

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

---

In this case `<Route path="/" component={Home} />` matches when the path is both `/` and `/foo` so `Home` is always rendered.

You can fix this by using either [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) so it only matches if the path is exactly `/`, or moving it to the end of the `Route` list so other routes match first:

```
test('Clicking link will render component associated with path', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/foo" />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/foo" component={MockComp} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  wrapper.find('a').simulate('click', { button: 0 });
  expect(wrapper.find('.protected')).toHaveLength(1);  // SUCCESS
});
```