# How to test the onClick routing event using Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a button with Link tag and routes to a new url and content onClick, basically calls a function.

I wanted to know if I can test whether the url is changed/new content is displayed post click, but I am not able to do so with 'simulate'. Is it possible to check that using jest/enzyme?

Comment: Have you tried to check the `window.location` like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977862/how-to-test-url-change-with-jest

Comment: yea, but post simulate, the url is not changing in the test.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775748/testing-click-behavior-on-react-router-links-with-enzyme

Comment: Thanks, I will try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I view you can test that using E2E testing.

I prefer https://www.cypress.io/, it is very easy for testing URL changing.

```js
cy.getByTestId('your_button')
  .click()
  .url()
  .should('include', 'expected_url')
```

FYI: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#No-Args

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.